# How to determine user defined function parameters names before calling it?

Tags: php

In PHP, I have created a user defined function. Example:

```
<?php
function test($one, $two) {
    // do things
}
?>
```

I would like to find the names of the function parameters. How would I go about doing this?

This is an example of what I would like:

```
<?php
function test($one, $two) {
    // do things
}

$params = magic_parameter_finding_function('test');
print_r($params);
?>
```

This would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
)
```

Also this is very important that I am able to get the user defined function parameter names outside the scope of the function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you EVER need to do something like this?

Comment: @coronatus you and me both are wondering the same thing?

Comment: Smells like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect

Comment: @Coronatus there are times you may want this.  Such as a documentation engine, or a way to map named parameters (to emulate python's functionality, so you could do `call_func_custom($callback, array('one' => 'foo', 'two' => 'bar'))`...  I'm not saying there are a lot of uses, but there definitely are uses...

Comment: Building a documentation generator, building an IoC/DI container... there are reasons. Not clear if the OP actually has a good reason for doing it, though. :)

Comment: I want to use it so that I can create a menu hook type in Drupal that expects an AJAX call. It will take in a POST of key / values and call the menu callback with it. Using call_user_func_array() the parameters must be ordered. I need it to write code that will order it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php)...

```
$reflector = new ReflectionFunction('test');
$params = array();
foreach ($reflector->getParameters() as $param) {
    $params[] = $param->name;
}
print_r($params);
```

Comment: Might need to be $params[] = $param->name ? Otherwise I think overall reflection is the right idea.

Comment: Also `new ReflectionMethod('class','method');` if looking at class methods rather than standalone functions. Along with the __call() magic method, I have used this to log method names, and parameter names against values for a particularly thorny section of code where I had to clearly see the data coming in for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

you can use count_parameter a php built in function